# How to search a string, pull a piece of it, and use it as a variable

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am working with router configurations and need to write a Python script to loop through a config file, search a specific string  for a specific item, in this case an IP address, store it as a variable, and then use that variable in another string.  For example:

```
interface Vlan88
  ip address 12.37.221.1 255.255.255.0
  !
  !
  standby 1 ip (insert ONLY 12.37.221.1 here)
```

And do this same thing for any and all other interfaces

I'll be honest....at present tries == 0 because this is beyond my knowledge level.  However, I am using regex to replace some helper addresses as well as write the HSRP config portion.  But, I am not far enough along to know how to search for something specific and turn it into a variable.

Comment: You should give exactly what your input and expected output is.

Comment: As mentioned, this is the input:
  interface Vlan88
  ip address 12.37.221.1 255.255.255.0
  !
  standby 1 ip

And the output should be:
interface Vlan88
  ip address 12.37.221.1 255.255.255.0
  !
  !
  standby 1 ip 12.37.221.1

Answer (score 0):

You should first check if the string exists in your config file, and if it does, concatenate to another string:

```
if <STRING> in open(<CONFIG FILE>).read():
      ip = <STRING>
     some_other_string += ip
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stack Overflow!

For this problem, you could...

- Load the config file data into a string variable, perhaps `contents`
- Use the `.find()` string method to search for a specfic keyword, such as `ip address`
- Use indexing to grab the next set of data: since `.find()` returns the index of the target word, you could then go about grabbing the next words unto you hit an End-Of-Line character, likely at least `\n`

[Here is a somewhat related problem that my help if you like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56977105/how-can-i-pull-out-text-snippets-around-specific-words/56978383#56978383)
[This may help as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157373/importing-data-and-variable-names-from-a-text-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

In general, when matching with re for example using `re.search(...)` you give a pattern and a target string. In the pattern you specify the structure of string you're looking for, and when using `(...)` inside your pattern, this creates *capture groups* that can be later retrieved. For example:

```py
s = "ip address 12.37.221.1 255.255.255.0"
mtch = re.search("ip address (\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+) .*")
print(mtch.group(0))
-> ip address 12.37.221.1 255.255.255.0
print(mtch.group(1))
-> 12.37.221.1
```

`group(0)` is always the full match, and then comes all your capturing groups.

For more details and examples, read [this section](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#grouping) of the cookbook

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you want to insert first IP address after  `"standby 1 ip"`. You can achieve this with regex capturing groups:

```
data = '''
interface Vlan88
  ip address 12.37.221.1 255.255.255.0
  !
  !
  standby 1 ip'''

import re

new_data = re.sub(r'(?<=ip address )([\d.]+)(.*)(standby 1 ip)', r'\1\2\3 \1', data, flags=re.DOTALL)

print(new_data)
```

Prints:

```
interface Vlan88
  ip address 12.37.221.1 255.255.255.0
  !
  !
  standby 1 ip 12.37.221.1
```

You can see inner workings of this regular expression on [Regex101 (link).](https://regex101.com/r/0KdWUN/1)